# Validar select com jQuery Validator

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate, jquery-ui-multiselect

Tenho um select como esse:

```
<form action="" id="form">
    <select name="unidadeNegocio[]" id="unidadeNegocio" multiple="multiple" >
        <option> A </option>
        <option> B </option>
        <option> C </option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Deixo esse `select` habilitado pra selecionar mais de uma opção com o [multiselect.js](http://loudev.com/) assim:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#unidadeNegocio').multiselect();
});
```

Tento validar se pelo menos uma opção do select foi selecionado com o [Validate](https://jqueryvalidation.org/category/methods/) (plugin pra validar inputs) assim:

```
$('#form').validate({
  rules: {
    "unidadeNegocio[]": {
      required: true,
      minlength: 1
    },
    messages: {
      "unidadeNegocio[]": {
        required: 'Por favor, selecione pelo menos um'
      }
    }
  }
})
```

O problema é que mesmo eu não selecionando nada no select, o formulário é submetido, não é validado.

Answer (score 1):

Você só tem um pequeno erro no seu script, o correto é `multiSelect` e não `multiselect`.

```js
$(function() { 
  $('#unidadeNegocio').multiSelect();
});

$('#form').validate({
  rules: {
    "unidadeNegocio[]": {
      required: true,
      minlength: 1
    },
    messages: {
      "unidadeNegocio[]": {
        required: 'Por favor, selecione pelo menos um'
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/multi-select/0.9.12/css/multi-select.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/multi-select/0.9.12/js/jquery.multi-select.min.js"></script>

<form action="" id="form">
  <select name="unidadeNegocio[]" id="unidadeNegocio" multiple="multiple">
        <option> A </option>
        <option> B </option>
        <option> C </option>
    </select>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: O código que você postou aqui funciona perfeitamente, mas aqui no meu ambiente não funciona, devo ter mais algum erro de sintaxe no meu código. +1 pra você.

Comment: Veja se tem algum erro no console do browser @LeandroLima. Talvez a biblioteca nao tenha sido carregada ainda..

Comment: Eu já vi, não tem erro nenhum. Outra coisa bizarra que eu observei é que se eu colocar `().multiSelect` não funciona corretamente, agora se eu por `().multiselect` funciona. Acho que alguém mexeu no core do plugin depois de importar pro projeto ):
Obrigado @Lucas Costa

Comment: Ou problema com versao. Tente colocar a mesma versao da documentacao, como eu fiz no exemplo. E veja se a versao eh compativel com a do jQuery, se tiver usando jQuery 3 pode acontecer problemas tambem.